# how to push values of different key of an object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object which have array of objects I want to get a new array with the values of inner objects value.

```
"vals": [{
            "vals_OwnGeneratingStation": [
                ["Hydel Power Station", "0.000"],
                ["Thermal Power Station", "0.000"],
                ["Small Hydel Units", "0.000"],
                ["Mini-Hydro", "0.000"]
            ]
        },
        {
            "vals_EnergyPurchaseWithinState": [
                [null, "0.000"]
            ]
        },
        {
            "vals_EnergyPurchaseOutsideState": [
                [null, "0.000"]
            ]
        },
        {
            "vals_Others": [
                [null, "0.000"]
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want an array with the values of "vals_OwnGeneratingStation","vals_OwnGeneratingStation","vals_EnergyPurchaseOutsideState","vals_Others"

The array will look like

```
newArray = [
[
  ["Hydel Power Station", "0.000"],
  ["Thermal Power Station", "0.000"],
  ["Small Hydel Units", "0.000"],
  ["Mini-Hydro", "0.000"]
],
[
 [null, "0.000"]
],
[
 [null, "0.000"]
],
[
 [null, "0.000"]
]
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `Object.values`

```
newArray =  vals.map( s => Object.values( s )[0] )
```

**Demo**

```js
var vals = [{
    "vals_OwnGeneratingStation": [
      ["Hydel Power Station", "0.000"],
      ["Thermal Power Station", "0.000"],
      ["Small Hydel Units", "0.000"],
      ["Mini-Hydro", "0.000"]
    ]
  },
  {
    "vals_EnergyPurchaseWithinState": [
      [null, "0.000"]
    ]
  },
  {
    "vals_EnergyPurchaseOutsideState": [
      [null, "0.000"]
    ]
  },
  {
    "vals_Others": [
      [null, "0.000"]
    ]
  }
];
var newArray = vals.map(s => Object.values(s)[0]);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
vals.map(item => Object.values(item));
```